# URL encoding in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, http-post

Can [VBScript escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3607h29%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) be used for escaping a post (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) or a multipart post? Is it the equivalent of PHP's [urlencode](http://us.php.net/urlencode)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`Server.URLEncode(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in place of PHP's `urlencode`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the equivalent, however it is perfectly suitable for escaping posts.

Comment: It's not. It doesn't escape "+".